# Not able to run a batch file from a java program

Tags: java

I want to run a batch file from a Java program.

This works:

```
runtime.getruntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\test.bat");  //Working
```

It is working very well, but if I give spaces in the path of the batch file, it is not working:

```
runtime.getruntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Program Files\\test.bat");  //Not Working
```

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put quotes around filenames with spaces in your command line:

```
runtime.getruntime().exec("cmd /c \"C:\\Program Files\\test.bat\"");
```

Comment: Hi Gabe Thanks for your reply.But i tried that one also but it is not working

Comment: @sivakumar: Did you use double backslashes for directory separators?

Comment: Yes i am using "\\" as directory saparators

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for anything to do with a `Process` in 1.5+.  (If using the [`List` based constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.util.List%29) it will likely solve the path problem.)
2. (General advice on this matter) Read and implement all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the spaces using `\`. Before each space just put a back slash `\`

Comment: Hi Jay Thanks for your reply.But i tried that one also but it is not working